# Override String in TextBox

Tags: vb.net

I have 3 text boxes on my form: *Surname, First Name and Middle Name*. I want to override my string. It looks like this:

> ...<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<... (Length = 36)

If I save a value and the text boxes contain `Surname:Bergs, First Name:John Paul, Middle Name:Dale`, and for sample purpose I want to display this in `MessageBox`, and should be like this

> `D<aleBergs<<John<Paul<<<<<<<<`

I have 2 objectives in this Question.

- How can I get the Text box specific value and display it on my string?
- If Text Box Contains space how can I turn it into `<` value?

**Update**

I solved Second Problem fix using this `String.Replace()`

```
Dim str As String = "John Paul"
Dim str2 As String = str.Replace(" ", "<")
MessageBox.Show(str2)
```

Comment: You have answer your question, which you should find out and try: how to retrieve value from text box, how to replace the value in string, or maybe how to padding string.  Please post your code if you encounter any problem.

Comment: Sorry i just made a progess just now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pre-fabricated string to have clear format

```
Dim outputFormat As String = "{0} {1} {2}"
MessageBox.Show(string.Format(outputFormat, txtMid.Text, txtFirst.Text, txtLast.Text))
```

You can also use format like {0, 10} or {0,-10} to get fixed positions, like this

> |John......|
>   |......John|

Where dots stand for spaces

Comment: How can I make the dots to `<` ?

Comment: @TKGhoul The dots in my answer represent spaces. There are 2 options. 1 - `.Replace(" ", "<")` 2 - `"John".PadRight(">", 7).PadLeft("<", 10)`. Second option will give you `<<<John>>>`. so, combination of Pad and Format, should be what you need

Answer (score 2):

If i'm right, You can get textbox inputs to separate string variables and concatenate them into one string variable or you can get all textbox values to one string variables like

```
Dim AllStrings As String

AllStrings = MiddleTextBox.Text &" "& FirstTextBox.Text &" "& LastTextBox.Text
```

Then you can replace spaces by using Replace Method.

```
AllStings = AllStrings.Replace(" ","<")
```

Hope this will helpful to you.